# Doctor CRM database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

[image]

I am designing a doctor CRM system. Now I need to have a list of patients in the doctor panel. what I do is I find all the bookings which are related to doctors and extract user data from there. Also, doctors need to add patients. so where can I add the patient and save the relation between doctor and user when the user is newly added without any booking history?

Comment: Well, if the relationships between doctors and their patients exist independently of "bookings", then `doctor_bookings` is the wrong place to store them. Also, whose `first_name`, `last_name`, and `phone` do you store in the bookings relation, and why?

Comment: @mustaccio no its not stored independently. my problem is this exactly.users can set booking with another name(for thir parant for example) thats why i store name and phone in booking. its just detail.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's going to be 1 doctor to be assigned to a user **at first**,
it makes sense to create a column in user-table to signify a
`default_doctor` to a user.

---

Extra :

PS : doesn't looks like this DB-design will scale.

- Doctors-table should ONLY contain doctor specific info, location, price should be in a separate table.
- perhaps you can think of a doctor as a user only and go from there.